# How to access jsonp data using Ext.util.JSONP.request

Tags: jquery, sencha-touch

I  am very new to sencha touch application, i've been tasked to get the json data from a cross domain and data looks like below

```
 { "data": { "error": [ {"msg": "Free API has moved to
 free.worldweatheronline.com\/feed\/weather.ashx url.
 Please make changes at your end. Please contact support team at
 info@worldweatheronline.com for any other issues." } ] }}
```

How to trigger a callback function for this json data,i can able to request but the callback function is not triggering.Can anyone help me out in this?thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you using JSONP request this way?

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
   url: 'YOUR JSONP URL',
   callbackName: 'someCallbackFunctionName',
   success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
   }
});
```

And you have to wrap the data you are returning in a function whose name you are passing as "callbackName" config. So, the data you will send from server must look like this:

```
someCallbackFunctionName({ "data": { "error": [ {"msg": "Free API has moved to
 free.worldweatheronline.com\/feed\/weather.ashx url.
 Please make changes at your end. Please contact support team at
 info@worldweatheronline.com for any other issues." } ] }})
```

Do check the [jsonp details](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonP) in Sencha API.

Comment: now can't access the server code,so is there any other way to wrap the callbackname

Comment: Then if you are using php, use cURL to get data from the url. Or if you are using some other technology, use their web services api to access data. You can access data directly from server side but not from browser.